# Get object keys if object value is true and key is in array. Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Consider the following object

```
let obj = {
   1:true,
   2:false,
   3:true
}
```

and some value like 
`let val = 1;` or `2`, whatever.

I want to get either true or false

In our example only for 1 and 3 it should return true.
I already tried this solution but when i test for 2 it still returns true when it should return false

```
const isFavourited =
      (Object.keys(obj).some(id => val == id &&
        Object.values(obj).some(value => value == true))
      );
```

Comment: You mean you want to test if key exists in obj and its also `true`?

Comment: Maybe try `obj[val]` instead

Answer (score 3):

You could take a function which checks the value.

```js
const check = k => object[k] === true;

var object = { 1: true, 2: false, 3: true };

console.log(check(1));
console.log(check(2));
```

Comment: This could be shortened to just `const check = k => object[k];`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let obj = {
   1:true,
   2:false,
   3:true
}

var val1 = 1,
    val2 = 2,
    val3 = 3,
    val4 = 4

function checkValue(key){
  return !!obj[key];
}
console.log(checkValue(val1));
console.log(checkValue(val2));
console.log(checkValue(val3));
console.log(checkValue(val4));
```

Answer (score 0):

The array function some returns true if one of the elements passes the check.

```
Object.values(obj).some(value => value == true))
```

When you are checking for the value here you're not specifying the id (the previous check for id is seperate). Therefore it checks all the elements of the array until one passes the check (index 0 will pass the check).

I recommend using Nina's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the following

```
const isFavourited =
      (Object.keys(obj).some(id => val == id &&
        Object.values(obj).some(value => value == true))
      );
```

You are not checking if the value of a particular index is `true` or `false`. Here is what actually happens when you have `val = 1`:

- the first `.some` will iterate over all keys
- `val == id` will be `true` for the second key which means:
- the `Object.values(obj).some(value => value == true)` will be executed
- it returns `true` because there is *at least one* value that is `true` in the entire `obj`. The *result* of this operation are not dependant on the value of the key - only whether it runs or not.

```js
let obj = { 1:true, 2:false, 3:true }

let check = Object.values(obj).some(value => value == true)

console.log(check);
```

So, the algorithm checks if `obj` contains a given key and *any* value that is `true`, as opposed to if the value *for* a given key is true.

You do not need to loop over the object to verify this - fetching the value of `obj[val]` is all you need - if the key `val` doesn't exist, you'd get `undefined` back, otherwise you'll get the value. So you merely need to check if the value you got back is `true` or not:

```js
let obj = { 1:true, 2:false, 3:true }

console.log(1,  obj[1]  == true);
console.log(2,  obj[2]  == true);
console.log(3,  obj[3]  == true);
console.log(42, obj[42] == true);
```

This can be further shortened to `!!obj[index]` using [implicit casting to boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = { 1:true, 2:false, 3:true };
//Create an temp object
let tempObj = {};

//Loop over keys and filter if key value is true and add to temp object
Object.keys(obj).filter((o)=> {if(obj[o]) tempObj[o] = obj[o]});

console.log(tempObj);
```